# POST canvas image from JavaScript to RESTful Web Services

Tags: javascript, java, html, json, rest

I'm currently implementing a tool whereby it needs to save canvas image from HTML JavaScript and upload the canvas image to RESTful web services using JSON.

I'm stuck at how to upload canvas image using JSON to webservices and how to implement code that retrieve the canvas image to Web services side using Java.

Comment: Could you please add some code that you have tried so far?

Comment: @asg here is some part of my javascript and html code. https://jsfiddle.net/mkL58yez/2/. Now im stuck on how to link the json to rest web services. i have no idea on how to code in java.

Answer (score 1):

I did that some time ago with storing thumbnails of canvas rendered picture. Basically canvas object has [toDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) method, I called it like toDataURL("image/png"), and stored it in hidden field in form, but you could as well send it directly with ajax call.

then basically I kept the image in that format in db, but you can store it on hard drive, probably more sustainable long term. example ruby/rails implementation of thumbnail retrieval:

```
def thumbnail
  render :status => 200,
         :content_type => 'image/png',
         :text =>  Base64.decode64(
           thumbnail["data:image/png;base64,".length .. thumbnail.length]
         ) # there is extra "data:image/png;base64," at the start
end
```

Comment: thank you, i have tried this method. part of example https://jsfiddle.net/mkL58yez/2/. Now im stuck on how to link the json to rest web services. i have no idea on how to code in java as im not sure the steps of converting the image file.

Comment: well, what you're sending right there is a json object with imageData property. I assume your backend accepts json formatted POST request, you access it just like that - via imageData field you created. once you have the data on the server, you can store file however you like - to file on hard drive, or to s3 cloud. you have to decode it from base64 first, and store it in binary format.